# where in the Rails 3 stack are cookie_store-based sessions verified?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Assuming one is using `:cookie_store`, rails session are stored client-side in a signed (but unencrypted) string in a cookie.

[Relevant documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions) implies that this signature is verified on the server for each request, but I haven't been able to track down where this actually happens. Where in the Rails stack is the session hash verified? Is there something I need to turn on or check?

This is distinct from  `protect_from_forgery`, which as I understand it serves to protect non-GET requests (e.g. form submissions), correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the actionpack gem. File action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb, line 291